# How can I prevent "only one usage of each socket..." error when accessing UdpClient using C#

Tags: c#, udp

I generated a plugin for a flight simulator.

When it loads it starts an endless loop which periodically reads the simulator data via UDP. During the game, the user can send command which may also read the simulator data via the same UDP port.
The problem is that sometimes I see this error message:

*"only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted"*.
I suspect that it is because I am trying to read from the same UDP port simultaneously.
Can this be the cause for this error?
If yes, I would like to add a checker before reading to data from the UDP to make sure it is not being currently accessed.
I think can check if a UDP is open like this:

```
            var alreadyinuse = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveUdpListeners().Any(p => p.Port == myPort);
```

However, this yields "false" even when the game is not running and the port is closed.
I want to know if the port is being accessed.
My code to read the game data looks like this:

```
        var dataRead = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(myIp), myPort);
        var receivingUdpClient = new UdpClient(myPort);
        var uSocket = receivingUdpClient.Client;
        var dataFromDcs = "";
        var RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(myIp), myPort);
        try
        {
            uSocket.ReceiveTimeout = _recieveTimeOut;
            var receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
            dataFromDcs = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
            if (Globals.ShowImportData)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is the message you received " + dataFromDcs);
                Console.WriteLine("This message was sent from " +
                                  RemoteIpEndPoint.Address +
                                  " on their port number " +
                                  RemoteIpEndPoint.Port);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        receivingUdpClient.Close();
```

Thanks